# Regular expression match over multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

My goal is match text inside parentheses (including them). This pattern works fine:`/(\-?\(.*\))/gm`, although it doesn't work on multiple lines.

Any ideas how to also "catch"

```
(INDISTINCT ANNOUNCEMENT
          OVER PA)
```

?

Here is the sample:

```
365
00:22:20,105 --> 00:22:21,772
         (CLAMOURING)

366
00:22:21,774 --> 00:22:25,009
      (INDISTINCT ANNOUNCEMENT
      OVER PA)

367
00:22:55,340 --> 00:22:58,509
      (INDISTINCT ANNOUNCEMENT
      OVER PA)

368
00:23:10,655 --> 00:23:11,389
      SARAH: Excuse me.
```

[Example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cP2hC8/1)

Comment: The period matches a single character, **with one single exception**, it does not match line break characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match content between `(` and `)` including newlines:

```
/\([\s\S]*?\)/g
```

In the absence of dotall flag in Javascript we use `[\s\S]` to make it match newlines as well.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iE0zG6/1)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `.` does not match the newline character. However, you can use `[^)]` to match everything except `)`, including newlines. e.g.

```
\([^)]*\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iE0zG6/2)